# JS / VueJs / Vuetify - Create a Tree from JSON object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tree, vuetify.js

I have a very large JSON object that I need to get into a tree but I'm unsure on how to do it. I'm using VueJs with Vuetify which has Treeview built in but I don't know how to actually get my data ready for the tree.

This is my data...

[image]

And what I need is this (obviously haven't included all the data)...

```html
items: [
    {
        name: "Adboom",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Jaydox LTD",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "beautifullyyoungskin.net"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "thinbodydiet.com"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "youthfulskincare.net"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Adult",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Occonti Ltd",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "datinginthe.eu (3d Secure)"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "datinginthe.eu (Non-3d)"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "datinginthe.eu - ST (Non-3d)"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "datinginthe.eu ST (3d Secure)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: you can use map to Restructuring data

Comment: Could you give me a little more information on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of keys for the wanted nested grouping of an object and try to find a `name` property with the wanted value of the level.

If found, return this item, otherwise add this item to the children property.

```js
var data = [{ divisionName: "Adboom", merchantName: "Jaydox LTD", entityName: "beautifullyyoungskin.net" }, { divisionName: "Adboom", merchantName: "Jaydox LTD", entityName: "thinbodydiet.com" }, { divisionName: "Adboom", merchantName: "Jaydox LTD", entityName: "youthfulskincare.net" }, { divisionName: "Adult", merchantName: "Occonti Ltd", entityName: "datinginthe.eu (3d Secure)" }, { divisionName: "Adult", merchantName: "Occonti Ltd", entityName: "datinginthe.eu (Non-3d)" }, { divisionName: "Adult", merchantName: "Occonti Ltd", entityName: "datinginthe.eu - ST (Non-3d)" }, { divisionName: "Adult", merchantName: "Occonti Ltd", entityName: "datinginthe.eu ST (3d Secure)" }],
    keys = ["divisionName", "merchantName", "entityName"],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            keys.reduce((t, k) => {
                var temp = (t.children = t.children || []).find(p => p.name === o[k]);
                if (!temp) {
                    t.children.push(temp = { name: o[k] });
                }
                return temp;
            }, r);
            return r;
        }, {})
        .children;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina, I need your help again if you don't mind. Your code has worked perfectly thus far but my project has slightly changed and needs a new requirement. As you can see in the screenshot in my original question, a division, merchant and entity all have ID columns (divisonId, merchantId, entityId). I require each node to contain an id element that contains the corresponding id. I've been trying to do this all day but can't do it. Hope you can help.

Comment: maybe you ask a new question with an extended data set (in text form), which reflects the needed properties.

Comment: Hi Nina, I have done that here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170369/create-a-json-hierarchical-tree-from-mysql-json-data